# Extjs creating combobox+textfield

Tags: extjs, combobox, textfield

I am trying to create textfield with dropdown like a combobox. Next behaviours is needed:

1. We can enter the text into textfield and set it even if the combobox doesn't contain this text,
2. Comboboxes behaviour as dropdowning tips.

So I've tried use mixins, but it's new to me and I don't understand it enough.

Comment: Which version of ExtJs are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

Which ExtJs version are you using? You can use Ext.form.field.ComboBox for that: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html

If you want to allow texts, that aren't defined in the combo, you just have to use:

```
forceSelection: false
```

when configuring the combo.